# how do i declare a jpanel as a variable in netbeans so i can use it to drag my form? [java swing]

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, awt

i would like to ask how do i declare a jpanel as a variable in netbeans so i can use it to drag my form? i am using netbeans gui builder to design the form.

(the code works, but i want it to drag the form only when i click on the top panel or the "header")

```
int pX, pY;

public void resizeDragJPFrame() {

    MainMenu f = new MainMenu();
    
    

    f.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            // Get x,y and store them
            pX = me.getX();
            pY = me.getY();
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
            f.setLocation(f.getLocation().x + me.getX() - pX,
                    f.getLocation().y + me.getY() - pY);
        }
    });

    f.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {

            f.setLocation(f.getLocation().x + me.getX() - pX,
                    f.getLocation().y + me.getY() - pY);
        }
    });

    f.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 500));
    f.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setUndecorated(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.pack();
}


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainMenu().resizeDragJPFrame();
        }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
}
```

Comment: I can't see any JPanel in your code, so your first step is to create one and add it to your JFrame, but if you have one then instead of referencing to your `MainMenu` object `f` like here `f.addMouseMotionListener(...` and here `f.addMouseListener(...` just replace `f` with your jpanel reference `yourPanel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {`.

Comment: I suggest you read one of **Rob Camick's** (aka: [@camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr)) blogs on this subject [here](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/). Rob is a heavy contributor in StackOverflow and is well versed in this topic.